# Vector Rotate scattered curves along mesh?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics, vector, vector-mapping

how can I rotate scattered curves(converted to mesh and realized) like upward the mesh they're scattered on? But not just upwards, I'd like to know how to do it in all directions along the surface of that mesh. I tried to draw the desired direction, I need I guess a local rotation of curves but with concidaration of that mesh somehow

I have the normal but it's obviously acting like local(to scattered curves) Z axis in vector rotate node
[image]

**UPDATE:**

I baked a tangent map with help of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273150/how-do-you-align-geometry-instances-to-mesh-tangent/273562#273562) post:
[image]

And it works with this setup in *Instance on Points* node:
[image]

But it does not work in *Set Position* node (kind of works but not really):
[image]

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: What, exactly, defines the direction you would like followed along the surface? If orthogonal to the normal, that still leaves 360° in 2D to choose from.